# How to iterate in-macro integer value in a variable-parameter-length C++ macro (... and VA_ARGS)?

Tags: c++, macros, switch-statement, preprocessor

I am trying to write a C++ macro which would substitue a frequently-needed verbose code like

```
switch (id) {
case 0:
    s << myFloat;
    break;
case 1:
    s << myInt;
    break;
default: break;
}
```

with something like `DESERIALIZE_MEMBERS(myFloat, myInt)`. `s` and `id` will not change names for the use case, so they don't need to be macro parameters.

It should support variable argument length, so `DESERIALIZE_MEMBERS(myString, myArrayOfInts, myLong)` for another case should also work, adding a third `case` statement to the switch expression.

However, it's not clear to me how to iterate the `N` value  in `case N:` inside the macro for each argument.

Is that possible at all in standard C++ macros?

Comment: I'd bind members to a tuple of references, then convert id to compile time constant and then std get/stream it.  Of course this doesn't need a macro, so doesn't match your ask.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont The workflow is part of a larger existing system that I cannot modify. I need to (many times) extend an existing class by overriding a function with a signature `(int id, stream s)`.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont I'm actually not sure if it's required for the function definition to be different in the approach you are suggesting. If you can point me in the right direction, where should I read about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), here is a solution.

First a compile-time constant type and value:

```
template<auto X>
using constant_t = std::integral_constant<decltype(X), X>;
template<auto X>
constexpr constant_t<X> constant_v;
```

Next, a variant over such constants:

```
template<auto...Is>
using enum_t = std::variant<constant_t<Is>...>;
```

this lets you generate a compile-time enumeration value at runtime and use it.

Now some code that lets you convert a runtime integer into a compile-time enumeration value:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr enum_t<Is...> get_enum_v( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t i ) {
  using generator = enum_t<Is...>(*)();
  constexpr generator generators[] = {
    +[]()->enum_t<Is...> {
      return constant_v<Is>;
    }...
  };
  return generators[i]();
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto get_enum_v( std::size_t i ) {
  return get_enum_v( std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, i );
}
```

so if you do `get_enum_v<10>(2)`, it returns an `enum_t<...>` with 10 alternatives containing the alternative with index 2, which is a `constant_v<std::size_t, 2>`.

Now we just get a tuple and an index, and we call a function on the tuple element described by the index:

```
template<class F, class Tuple>
auto apply_to_nth_element( std::size_t i, F f, Tuple tuple ) {
  constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<Tuple>{};
  auto Index = get_enum_v<N>( i );
  return std::visit( [&](auto I){
    return f( std::get<I>(tuple) );
  }, Index );
}
```

you can now do this:

```
apply_to_nth_element(id, [&](auto& elem) {
  s << elem;
}, std::tie(myFloat, myInt));
```

instead of

```
DESERIALIZE_MEMBERS(myFloat, myInt)
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/cd6YovEjv); Code can be rewritten in versions older than [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) but gets extremely ugly very fast.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very in-depth explanation of the idea and the implementation.

Will try to use this, and in case any issues appear, will update the comment with necessary edits.

Comment: @goose_lake Version that compiles and runs edited in, and live example linked.  Just a few typos (missing `;`, missing variable name).